# Hidding my private key RSA on angular front-end app

Tags: angular, cryptography, key, rsa

I am new to Stack Overflow. I am developing a digital signature application in spring boot (back-end) and angular(front-end). I have already set up a keycloak server for authentication and rights management ... The purpose of digital signature is for the server to send its public key, hash the document, encrypt the document hash with its private key and sending the document unhashed and the suggestion obtained by encrypting the document. I am using an RSA protocol. I would like to do the same for the front-end part, ie the client has a private key only sends the public key to the server, the server then decrypts with this public key. But I don't know where to put my private key or front-end level, at my Angular application level, so that it cannot be stolen.

Comment: Hiding from whom?

Comment: Hiding from a hacker for example who try to sign the document, or modify the document, on my behalf, if he had the private key he can do anything he can encrypt the document sign on my behalf and sent it to the back-end

Comment: If you want the front end user to sign stuff then you should only send them the private key after authenticating them properly.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately this is impossible. Any code, keys, etc. you give to the client (Angular app) will be able to be read, either in plain text or by inspection of your code, by a user.

You should never give your client private keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I wanted to know how can I then do to sign (a document) on the front end side and be sure that this data has not been modified by a third person other than the person who signed the document before the reception of this document by the back-end side. The rsa protocol recommends using a private key to generate the signature of the document and a public key to send to the recipient to "decrypt, I don't understand what to do if I can't have a front-end private key. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide any code on front-end. It is recommended against storing sensitive data on front-end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I wanted to know how can I then do to sign (a document) on the front end side and be sure that this data has not been modified by a third person other than the person who signed the document before the reception of this document by the back-end side. The rsa protocol recommends using a private key to generate the signature of the document and a public key to send to the recipient to "decrypt, I don't understand what to do if I can't have a front-end private key. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

Store the private key on the server, authenticate all users properly, authorize all requests and let the server act as a proxy for signing operations.

Comment: This is probably the best option, but another would be to have them choose a certificate they already have to use to sign the document, and send the public key of said certificate to the server.

Comment: @BlackICE Yes, this would work, but would assume that the use case is that the user of the front end owns the private key. But I think this doesn't correspond the OPs use case. They are the server owner as well as the private key owner. I might be wrong.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you for you response, but I don't really catch what do you mean by authorizing all requests and let server act as proxy for signing operations. I'm debutant I don't really catch what you mean. Do you mean that I don't need to have a private key in front-end app ? If it's the case how can I sign my document to check the integrity off the document in back-end part ? I don't really catch, thank you very much in advance

Comment: @almutanabbi If the user loads your application in the browser, they will either be presented with a login screen or they might use your web app directly. If there is a login screen then the server needs to check their password and if it is valid give them a session cookie. Afterwards, each request contains a session cookie authenticating the user. On each request the server should decide whether the request is valid (the user is permitted to do this specific operation like uploading a document). The request itself should go over TLS which provides confidentiality and integrity....

Comment: @almutanabbi ... The server is guaranteed to receive valid and complete data or there was an error. In this case, the client doesn't need an RSA private key to sign documents and the recipient is the server, because that is what TLS is doing. If the recipient of the signed document is a third party then the private key should be kept on the server and signed only then when the server actually permitted the user to upload a document and accepted the command to send that signed document to a third party.